# - (NSString *)instanceMethod

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Dear iPhone Developers, 
I have an instance method which is meant to return a string

```
- (NSString *)newFile:(NSString *)inFile andFileNumber:(NSInteger)aNumber {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.o%i",inFile,aNumber];
}
```

I call this method as

```
outputFileName = [self newFile:inputFileName andFileNumber:newNumber];
// where inputFileName is a string and newNumber is an integer 
// outputFileName (also a string), inputFileName and newNumber are declared in
// the interface and in the implementation
```

When I compile the project with Analyzer, it gives the following messages;

1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count (non-owning reference)
2. Object returned to caller with a +0 (non-owning) retain count
3. Object with +0 retain counts returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

Also when it tries to release outputFileName the application crashes. Does somebody has any clue what is going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is an assumption of convention.   Specifically, the static analyzer assumes that any method that starts with `new` returns a retained object.   This is because the system APIs follow this convention.

Rename your method;  `fileNameWithBase:fileNumber:` comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your method starts with "new" with the analyzer assumes means that you want to return an object with a +1 retain count. Change the name of the method and the warnings should go away.

Also: the method returns an autoreleased object; you shouldn't be releasing it yourself.

Comment: Dear kubi, thank you very much. It was this "new" that confusing the analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an autoreleased string.  If you're sending it an additional `-release` or `-autorelease` message, your app will crash the next time it tries to access that string.

You should take the time to read the "memory management" section of Apple's developer documentation.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the method, other than the name confuses the static analyzer.